# How to run a sudo command silently on the server?

Tags: linux

I need to execute this command on Linux server.

```
string command = $"sudo iptables -I INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport {port} -j ACCEPT";
```

When I run the app in VirtulBox, the terminal asks me for a password.
Will this also happen on the server? I can't login to the server and don't know the password.
How can I run the command so that it does not ask for password?

Comment: from the answers you gave to the solution proposed by @Nedry below, this is a problem, with the level of permissions you are granted on the server and nothing else. Either you:

1 - ask for root
2 - ask to have a user that can sudo without password
3 - ask somebody that have root access to put that rule in place

Comment: @fun_times So you are saying that it is impossible to run iptables automatically from within an application on the server?

Comment: this is not what I said. if your application run as root, this will be no problem whatsoever.

Comment: but since I saw from your other comments that this is a ec2 that gets deploy with auto scaling group, you may have a chance to add your rule in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-add-user-data.html

Comment: you should also edit your question to mention this is ultimately to deploy in a ec2 auto scaling group without ssh access since this is relevant

Comment: and now that I think of it, iptables will be useless if the security group does not have that same specific rule. and if it does, iptables is useless.

Comment: @fun_times Thanks! I did think about this actually. I plan to add the "security group" programmatically using the API at runtime. I was thinking that before doing it, I need to open the ports, just like I open the firewall ports on windows. Are you saying that on Linux I don't need to modify the iptables, and only the "security group" entry is enough to access the box? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: correct, security groups are enough... adding iptables to the mix is like a double firewall (useless)

Answer (score 1):

Login to the terminal as root. Make a backup of your /etc/sudoers file.
`# cp /etc/sudoers /root/sudoers.bak`

Then edit this file by using the visudo command:
`# visudo`

Edit or append this line, replacing username with the user that will be running your script:
`username ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/iptables`

Save and exit the file.
Test it by executing sudo, from your user account:
`$ sudo iptables -V`

Now your user can use sudo to execute the iptables command.

Comment: I can't login as root to no where. The system is automatically stared and run on the server. There is an everchanging array of computers that are being created automatically and having their software deployed to them automatically and run. You can't expect me to do an SSH every time a new computer is created?

Answer (score 0):

If you whant to do this from Linux machine:
You can writ a script with:

```
sshpass -p "PASSWORD" user@server
```

and give only execute premition.

Comment: I would happily do it, but I don't understand your code. I am executing this command inside a .NET app, using process invocation. The process FileName is "/bin/bash". It is deployed automatically on EC2, so I don't know the password.

Comment: sshpass alow you to pass the password with your command, 
just install sshpass and run:
sshpass -p "PASSWORD" string command = $"sudo iptables -I INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport {port} -j ACCEPT";

Comment: What password? I don't have any passwords... This an EC2 server that is being created automatically in auto-scale. How do you expect me to install sshpass, when I don't login to the system?

Comment: You didnt say it's EC2, In that case I can't help you.